# Plugging in a second monitor causing strange errors

Tags: ubuntu, display

I have a laptop running 16.04 LTS (kernel 4.4.0-190-generic). I have a CableCreation USB-C to HDMI adapter that I'm using to try and plug the second monitor into (there is no HDMI port on the laptop). When I plug the monitor into the adapter, a whole mess of strange errors occur. The second monitor zooms super close on the top right corner of the screen where my username is, the mouse becomes nearly useless for anything besides moving the cursor, I can't click on any settings, right click, or really interact with anything on the screen. The main screen shows a lot of weird blinking and stuff too.

Please let me know what other information I should supply to help get this solved or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I was able to finally access the display settings for the external monitor and for some strange reason the display scaling was set to like 48x and that was causing a ton of issues. I just changed that back down 1x and everything works fine now.